# fetch data using rest api and push it using a soap function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, soap

I am getting the data using the fetch request from a server, now I need to push the data using soap `addSubscriber`. For that I have created a client can someone please tell me, how can I pass the data  to `addSubscriber`.

```
// to get the data
const getData = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/user/2");
  if (resp.ok) {
    return await resp.json();
  } else {
    console.log(resp.status);
    console.log("error");
  }
};
const userData = await getData();
console.log(userData);`

// to push data

`const addSubscriber = async () => {
  const createSoapClient = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    soap.createClient(wsdlUrl, authtoken, (err, client) =>
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(client)
    )
  );
  console.log(await createSoapClient)
  const soapClient = await createSoapClient;
  const data = await soapClient.addSubscriber();
  return data.result;
};
console.log(await addSubscriber());
```

Comment: functions take arguments ... call `addSubscriber(userData)` ... and rewrite `addSubscriber` to take an argument ... `const addSubscriber = async (data) => {` for example